# df.to_csv() as tab-delim but commas conflict

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv, tabs

I want to save a DataFrame as tab-delimited .csv

```
df.to_csv('df.csv', index=False, sep ='\t')
```

However, the 3rd column has a list object, which coincidentally holds commas: `,`.

Because of this, my output `df.csv` has many columns. The first being 3 values, correctly delimited by tabs. The second and more are comma split values.

---

df (correctly: 3 columns):

```
            0                                                  1  \
0   Emissions  305-1~GHG emissions in metric tons of CO2e~Gro...   
1   Emissions  305-1~GHG emissions in metric tons of CO2e~Bio...   
2   Emissions    305-1~Direct (Scope 1) GHG emissions by gas~CO2   
3   Emissions    305-1~Direct (Scope 1) GHG emissions by gas~N20   
4   Emissions   305-1~Direct (Scope 1) GHG emissions by gas~HFCs   
5   Emissions   305-1~Direct (Scope 1) GHG emissions by gas~PFCs   
6   Emissions    305-1~Direct (Scope 1) GHG emissions by gas~SF6   
7   Emissions  305-2~GHG Emissions in metric tons of CO2e~Gro...   
8   Emissions  305-2~GHG Emissions in metric tons of CO2e~Gro...   
9   Emissions  305-2~GHG Emissions in metric tons of CO2e~Tot...   
10  Emissions  305-2~GHG Emissions in metric tons of CO2e~Tot...   
11  Emissions  103-1~Explanation of the material topic and it...   
12  Emissions   103-2~The management approach and its components   
13  Emissions        103-3~Evaluation of the management approach   

                                                    2  
0   [2014_2760, 2015_278585, 2016_409886, 2017_972...  
1   [2014_299605, 2015_477610, 2016_822657, 2017_8...  
2   [2014_444055, 2015_730929, 2016_766490, 2017_8...  
3   [2014_510811, 2015_583265, 2016_694522, 2017_7...  
4   [2014_162816, 2015_199622, 2016_228775, 2017_3...  
5   [2014_61824, 2015_569032, 2016_607814, 2017_77...  
6   [2014_60442, 2015_64418, 2016_329338, 2017_784...  
7   [2014_53078, 2015_500448, 2016_527776, 2017_61...  
8   [2014_165580, 2015_557426, 2016_894641, 2017_9...  
9   [2014_60142, 2015_84502, 2016_532996, 2017_893...  
10  [2014_71762, 2015_72349, 2016_195351, 2017_624...  
11  consumption rate fossil fuels coal oil emissio...  
12  how evaluate companys environmental management...  
13  evaluation effectiveness companys environmenta...
```

`df.csv` (incorrect, technically I want *one* column but for the original 3 column-values to be tab-delimited):
[image: screenshot row]

##### Simplified template example

df:

```
text | text | ['list', 'object', 'here', 'of', 'any', 'length']
text | text | ['foo', 'bar']
```

Desired .CSV [one literal column, but with values separated by tabs (->)]:

```
| text -> text -> ['list', 'object', 'here', 'of', 'any', 'length'] |
| text -> text -> ['foo', 'bar'] |
```

**One column output, with values separated by tabs. No headers or indexes**

---

**How do I ensure that Pandas ignores the `,` of the list object?**

Please let me know if I should provide any further details.

Comment: Can you please provide the `DataFrame` you are working with?

Comment: Sure, I might be a while but rerunning it

Comment: A sample will be enough too.

Comment: Provided sample... hopefully I'm explaining it ok

Comment: I've added a simplified template. I think the values of my `df` can be off putting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, you could just click "copy value" (semantics differ in each IDE) on your `df` in the variable viewer (again, name changes depends on IDE) to copy it's data in a way I could copy it, but I created a sample from what you have provided.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
```

sample df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['Emissions', 'Emissions'], 'col2': ['305-1~GHG emissions in metric tons of CO2e~Gro...', '305-1~GHG emissions in metric tons of CO2e~Bio...'], 'col3': [['2014_2760, 2015_278585, 2016_409886'], ['[2014_299605, 2015_477610, 2016_822657']]})
```

<strike>Now the trick here is to use the `quoting` parameter which according to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) is:</strike>

<strike>> **quoting** : ***optional constant from csv module***</strike>

> Defaults to csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL. If you have set a float_format then floats are
> converted to strings and thus csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC will treat them as
> non-numeric.

---

### **Edit:**

After clarifying your objective, `apply` should make it happen:

```
df = df[df.columns].apply(
    lambda x: ' -> '.join(x.astype(str)),
    axis=1)
```

Save file:

```
df.to_csv('sample.csv', index=False)
```

output:
[image]

Comment: Oh, I tried to just add the `sep='\t', index=False` params but for some reason it didn't save the file at all, I'm working remotely and Google Colab has it's shticks

Comment: I've since learnt that all data in .csv are strings. So converting the list objects to strings won't help ;(

Comment: Ok I think I got something, going to edit my post

Comment: I'm running my code with a `' '.join()` around my list objects, before they are added to the `df`... This works but isn't a comma-separated list object clearly.

Comment: Check it out and tell me your feedback.

Comment: I didn't think of using a different delamination. Hypothetically, if when I import the csv, I can then reference `->` to split them off as columns again. Thank you :)

Comment: You can replace ` -> ` with `\t` or anything else, it just was easier for me to actually see the difference in `MS Excel`

Comment: Ah ok, gotcha. Cheers